# Change cell colour in Excel file based on a value in another Excel file

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm not sure it it possible, I'm totally new to Microsoft Teams, so please bear with me.

This is the problem:
There are **two** Excel files which live on a **shared drive** on Teams - input & output.
I would like to automate the workflow which right now is too manual:

1. Go to the input file and find an ID where the cell is filled with red colour
2. Find this ID in the output file and check its status (another column)
3. If the status is "ON", go back to the input file and change the colour of the cell to green

Is it actually possible to automate this process?

Input: find ID with red fill

| ID | Column |
| --- | --- |
| 1(red) | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | c |

Output: check the status of the ID

| ID | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | On |
| 2 | Off |
| 3 | Off |

Input: change colour of the cell

| ID | Column |
| --- | --- |
| 1(green) | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | c |

Answer (score 0):

After days of experimenting, I found a way to do it. Below is the script you need to create as macro. Make sure the Input file is macro-enabled (xlsm).

You need to open both files "in app", create a macro from the Input file and run it/save it. It should update it in the cloud. Worked for me!

```
Sub CheckStatus()
    Dim inputWB As Workbook, outputWB As Workbook
    Dim inputWS As Worksheet, outputWS As Worksheet
    Dim inputID As Range, outputID As Range
    Dim outputStatus As String
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
   
    ' Set file paths and worksheet names
    Set inputWB = Workbooks("input.xlsm")
    Set outputWB = Workbooks("output.xlsx")
    Set inputWS = inputWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set outputWS = outputWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
   
    ' Find the first orange cell in column A of the input file
    For Each inputID In inputWS.Range("A:A")
        If inputID.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then Exit For
    Next
       
    ' Loop through all orange cells in column A of the input file
    Do Until inputID Is Nothing
        ' Find the corresponding ID in column A of the output file
        Set outputID = outputWS.Range("A:A").Find(what:=inputID.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not outputID Is Nothing Then
            ' Check the status in column B of the output file
            outputStatus = outputID.Offset(0, 1).Value
            If outputStatus = "On" Then
                ' Change the color of the ID cell to green (or use RGB code) in the input file
                inputID.Interior.Color = vbGreen
            End If
        End If
        ' Find the next orange cell in column A of the input file
        Set inputID = inputWS.Range("A:A").Find(what:="*", after:=inputID)
        If inputID.Interior.Color <> RGB(255, 192, 0) Then Exit Do ' Exit loop if new color found
    Loop
   
    ' Close workbooks
    inputWB.Close savechanges:=True
    outputWB.Close savechanges:=False
End Sub
```